# avoid persistance of a variable

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I am trying to persist an entity class here

```
@Entity

@Table(name="team")

public class Team {

    @Id
    protected String teamId;

    protected String teamName;
    protected String teamDescription;
    protected Date createdOn;

    protected String teamLeader;

// all getter setter methodes

}
```

The problem is teamLeader in not a field in the team table. I am just using it just to get its value from the form and using it somewhere else. how can i avoid persisting it as it is getting persisted like all other members. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate a field with the [`@Transient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) annotation to denote to the JPA implementation that it should not be persisted in the database.

```
@Transient
protected String teamLeader;
```